# RBAC with Django REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, authorization, rbac, abac

Any suggestions on what I should use to integrate RBAC with DRF? I have taken a look at django-rest-framework-roles and django-guardian but neither look too promising. Your feedback would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into [tag:abac] and [tag:xacml]

Answer (score 1):

What I have done was Create endpoint for `Users`, `Groups` and `Permissions` and used the `DjangoModelPermissions` in conjunction of `TokenAuthentication`.

You can overwrite the `User` model as `abstractUser` or you can use it as it is.

Create the serializers for `Users`, `Permissions` and `Group`.

I personally followed this approach:

rbac/api/viewsets.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from customuser.models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Custom User for authentication """
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        read_only_fields = ["is_superuser"]
        fields = [
        "id",
        "is_superuser",
        "username",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "email",
        "password",
        "is_staff",
        "is_active",
        "date_joined",
        "last_login",
        "is_admin",
        "is_insurer",
        "groups",
        ]

    # hash password
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(CustomUserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

class PermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Add permissions serializer """
    class Meta:
        model = Permission
        fields ='__all__'

class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """ Add group serializer """
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="customuser:groups-detail")
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['url', 'name', 'permissions']
```

And for rbac/api/viewsets.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from customuser.models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer, GroupSerializer, PermissionSerializer
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, DjangoModelPermissions
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication


class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
    # remove these two lines to remove auth
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    authentication_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows view/create/edit/delete groups.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    # remove these two lines to remove auth
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    authentication_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

class PermissionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Permission.objects.all()
    # remove these two lines to remove auth
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    authentication_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

If you dont already know, the builting django's `Group` class has a manyToMany relationship with the `Permission` class. Therefore, you should follow the same approach in the `GroupSerializer` class. Instantiating the permission serializer class inside the Group serializer class and passing a `many=True`.

Like this when you create a group you will be able to pass permissions to it from the api.

Inside the app which I called `rbac` you can create another `url.py` file and add the following code:

rbac/url.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .api.viewsets import CustomUserViewSet, GroupViewSet, PermissionViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('customuser', CustomUserViewSet, basename='customuser')
router.register('groups', GroupViewSet, basename='groups')
router.register('permission', PermissionViewSet, basename='permission')


app_name='customuser'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

(Dont forget to include() this url.py to the main url.py)

In your `settings.py` you should add your `rbac` app, `rest_framework` and `rest_framework.token` if you will authenticating by token your users.

settings.py:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
    'rbacr', 
    'rest_framework', 
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]

# if you created a customUser model as AbstractUSer
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'rbac.CustomUser'


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',<==== SET THE CORE DJANGO PERMISSION INSTEAD
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Like this your endpoints should look like this:

api/ root:

```
{
    "customuser": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customuser/",
    "groups": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/groups/",
    "permission": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/permission/"
}
```

api/customuser:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "username": "anyname",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$260000$gD........",
        "is_staff": true,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2021-05-24T02:16:00Z",
        "last_login": "2021-05-26T02:57:30.215345Z",
        "groups": [
            3,   <==== 
            4    <==== 
        ]
    }
```

These are the groups created using the drf api itself.

api/group:

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/groups/1/",
        "name": "admin_group",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "id": 21,
                "name": "Can add user",
                "codename": "add_customuser",
                "content_type": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 25,
                "name": "Can view user",
                "codename": "can_view_user",
                "content_type": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "name": "Can change user",
                "codename": "change_customuser",
                "content_type": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "name": "Can delete user",
                "codename": "delete_customuser",
                "content_type": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 24,
                "name": "Can view user",
                "codename": "view_customuser",
                "content_type": 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/groups/2/",
        "name": "insurer_group",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "id": 25,
                "name": "Can view user",
                "codename": "can_view_user",
                "content_type": 6 <======= CUSTOM USER ID
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/groups/3/",
        "name": "whatever_group",
        "permissions": [] <=====  ONLY VIEW --- NEED A SMALL CHANGE TO REMOVE VIEW
    }
]
```

For the api/permissions will be displayed all permissions for all classes/tables.

With this approach you can create groups with custom permissions and assign them to Users as shown on the first endpoint. Each group will have an `id` in the `customuser` endpoint, then, if you want, you can add a script to modify them showing the name instead. Like this you will be able to extend the admin to be used as you wish and assign permissions for each group and add more than one group to a user. In my view, groups can also be view as role.

I would recommend you to check:

1- [DjangoModelPermissions](http://teams.microsoft.com/_?lm=deeplink&lmsrc=homePageWeb&cmpid=WebSignIn#/conversations/19:2c2bdb39-c54d-4b89-8765-6ec02d2181c7_9e26015a-6edb-4c7e-a692-7a9feace4ed9@unq.gbl.spaces?ctx=chat)
2- Django [Group and Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/)

I am intermediate with django and if you have a better answer for this question I will be grateful. Since there are few answers about this topic for django.